# Flutter FLCharts Grid not rendering correctly

Tags: flutter, fl-chart

I am showing a chart in my Flutter App using [fl_chart](https://pub.dev/packages/fl_chart) library.
I am trying to show spots with an y value of either 1, 2, or 3 and I want to draw a horizontal line on the chart on the values 1, 2 and 3.

Here is my code:

```
class MyChart extends StatelessWidget {
  final List<ScatterSpot> spots;

  const MyChart({
    Key? key,
    required this.spots,
  }) : super(key: key);

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return ScatterChart(
      ScatterChartData(
        minX: 1,
        maxX: 5,
        minY: 1,
        maxY: 3,
        scatterSpots: spots,
        gridData: FlGridData(
          show: true,
          drawHorizontalLine: true,
          drawVerticalLine: false,
          getDrawingHorizontalLine: (value) {
            return FlLine(
              color: Colors.grey.shade300,
              strokeWidth: 1,
            );
          },
          horizontalInterval: 1,
        ),
        borderData: FlBorderData(
          show: false,
        ),
        titlesData: FlTitlesData(
          leftTitles: SideTitles(
            showTitles: true,
            getTitles: (value) => value.toString(),
            interval: 1,
          ),
          rightTitles: SideTitles(
            showTitles: false,
          ),
          topTitles: SideTitles(
            showTitles: false,
          ),
          bottomTitles: SideTitles(
            showTitles: false,
          ),
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

So, as you can see, I have defined a minY Value of 1 and a maxY Value of 3. I am drawing a horizontal line with an Interval of 1. The Titles on the y-axis are shown correctly for 1, 2 and 3, but the line is only drawn for the value 2, not for the values 1 and 3. How can I fix this?

Answer (score 0):

Fixed it ^^
I just set borderData with bottom and top BorderSide

Answer (score 0):

```
gridData: FlGridData(
              show: true,
              getDrawingHorizontalLine: (value) {
                return FlLine(color: RED, strokeWidth: 1);
              },
              checkToShowHorizontalLine: (value) {
                // final val = 100;
                // if (value % (val.floor() * 50 / val.floor()) == 0) {
                  return true;
                // }
                // return false;
              },
              getDrawingVerticalLine: (value) {
                return FlLine(color: BLUE, strokeWidth: 5);
              },
              checkToShowVerticalLine: (value) => true,
              drawHorizontalLine: true,
              drawVerticalLine: true)
```

Comment: can draw verticles as well as a horizontal line

Comment: Please avoid code only answer and provide an explanation. You also could have a look at [how to answer](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 0):

You can use the `extraLinesData` in `BarChartData` to draw custom lines in your chart canvas.

`defaultGridLine()` is a function provided by the `fl_charts` library itself.

```dart
BarChartData(
  extraLinesData: ExtraLinesData(
  horizontalLines: <HorizontalLine>[
    HorizontalLine(
      y: /* max value, 3 in your case */,
      dashArray: defaultGridLine(0).dashArray,
      strokeWidth: defaultGridLine(0).strokeWidth,
      color: defaultGridLine(0).color,
    );
  ],
),
```